# How to open a .exe file?

Tags: python

May someone please tell me how to set up code in Python that will allow me to open an `.exe` file?
The file location is:

> C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\New Folder\ksp-win-0-21-1\KSP_win cosmetic mods

and the file is called:

> KSP.exe

Shorter code would be preferred, but it does not matter that much.

I don't know if it would make a difference, but I am using a Windows 7 computer.

Comment: What do you mean by "opening" an exe file? Running it?

Comment: yes, but in a new window, not inside the python window. i dont know if this will make a difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\Users\Public\Videos\Sample Videos\New Folder\ksp-win-0-21-1\KSP_win cosmetic mods\KSP.exe"])
```

Comment: Thankyou! this helps a lot, but is there a way to copy-paste into python?

Comment: @user2762603: You just need to copy this code file in a file and run it by typing in a console `python file.py`

Answer (score 0):

Another way to run an exe is through the os.system command:

```py
import os
os.system("Path\\to\\file.exe")
```

The os.system command will allow you to run commands as if they were in your command prompt.

Comment: No problem. The advantage to using the subprocess design rather than using os.system is that sub process gives you a function called popen(...) which allows your program to continue even as the EXE is running. os.system will lock the program until the exe is closed or quits.